# Azure Datafactory ~ Get newest file in container

Tags: azure-data-factory

I think this question may have come up before but I have not been able to locate a clear or clean answer which properly addresses the situation. Given the likelihood for how common this operation must be I can't help but feel that there must be a good way to do this without layers of complexity.

Scenario:
I have a storage account container into which an application is sending data files at varying rates. If the application is experiencing demand it may push a data file into that container once a minute. If the application is not in demand the data files may be written one every couple of minutes. In either extreme for the scenario the metadata for the file is the source of truth: the latest file, the one I need to process, has the most up to date last modified time in the meta data.

The patterns I see for 'getting' the latest file all require you to get the metadata.childitems of the container, then link that to a foreach which then gets the metadata for each file in turn, this time you can get at the last modified property. It is also possible to filter that with the filter by last modified 'Start time' and 'End time'.

This pattern does not seem to work for me because if the application is busy and I am using that filter to return files from E.g. the last two minutes I may well get back two or even three files. I need to use the last couple of minutes as a window because if the application has not been busy then I need that window to catch the last single file (which might have been two minutes ago).

I thought that the filter activity, would have provided a 'sort' function to allow me to at least sort the files that I get back (from the two minute window) then select or filter-in the latest one, but that does not seem to be possible.

Fundamentally, all I am looking for is a solid pattern for getting the single newest file in that container - surely that is a common use case?

At the moment, I am thinking it may be necessary for the pipeline to call a function app which does the work of locating the file I need, then renaming it. That way all Datafactory would need is a dataset pointing to that filename - but I can't help but feel accomplishing something this simple should be do-able in Datafactory itself without having to make a function app (just for that).

I would be very grateful for any suggestions on how this can be accomplished.

Comment: Just for now, there isn't a good way to get the latest file. Only the  metadata could get the file property 'last modified time'.  As you said, there should be an 'sort' function in filter active or Get Metadata active, we also hope so.  We can't answer you with other solutions or workarounds. Per my expression, I would suggest you post your request/problem to the Data Factory feedback: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory.

Comment: Hi @Indrid, do you have any other concerns?

Comment: Thanks Leon. Appreciate the information.

Comment: You're welcome. May I post it as answer? Hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a round-about way as follows:

- Create a pipeline variable of type Array
- Get Metadata for the folder
- Loop through the childitems as you mentioned in your post
- In the loop, use AppendVariable to add the fileModified date for each childitem to your array variable
- Outside the loop, put your Copy Data activity to get the newest file
- Use max(variables.myArrayVariable) in the date filter of your copy activity to get just the newest file

If I understand correctly, your app could write new files during the pipeline run - so at the point of the copy there might be newer files than the newest file you just identified.  I would suggest you use pipeline().TriggerTime as the upper limit for the metadata and copy activities, then anything new since the pipeline began will be picked-up on the next run (unless there's an even newer file by then).

Comment: Very creative. I like this idea. Not as simple as it should be, but a fine way to get the relevant values into the filter window.

Answer (score 1):

Just for now, there isn't a good way to get the latest file. Only the metadata could get the file property 'last modified time'. We need to filter the file according this property.

As you said, there should be an 'sort' function in filter active or Get Metadata active, we also hope so. We can't answer you with other solutions or workarounds. Per my expression, I would suggest you post your request/problem to the Data Factory feedback:https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory .

We can help you vote it and Data Factory product team can see it.

HTH.

Answer (score -1):

I tried a different approach for a similar problem. I noticed that getmetadata activity returns the file names in ascending order. so in the child items array file1 will come first, followed by file2, file3 etc.

I used the following steps.

get child items using a getmetadata activity

define a sting variable v_filename

iterate child items through foreach loop

inside the foreach loop use a setvariable activity which will overwrite the
v_filename in each iteration. After the final iteration the variable will have the latest file name

use your copy activty after the foreach and pass v_filename as filename.

it works

Comment: Be careful using Set Variable activity in parallel For Each activity as the scope of the variable is at pipeline level.  This can lead to problems, so either set the For Each to sequential or do not use a variable - simply use the same expression you use to set the variable in the activity, not the variable.  NB running things in sequential mode can really slow things down.

Comment: The foreach is running in sequential and the variable is being used in the copy activity after and outside the foreach. There is a date filter in the get metadata so that it won't bring all the files in the directory.  Essential the loop will be only 2 or 3 files.