# Dynamically load file from blob storage in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a multiple parquet files in blob storage. I have to take the latest file from blob and process in ADF (copy activity or data flow) as source. Is there anyway to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use get meta data activity to list down all the files present in source and filter the latest file to be used in copy activity

Comment: I used getmetadata and retrieved the child items and then a foreach loop with getmetadata activity inside to fetch the lastmodified data and i am unsure on what to do next (how to filter out the latest one)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/136815/lates-file-extraction-azure-data-factory.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66509234/azure-datafactory-get-newest-file-in-container

this link would provide all the details

Answer (score 0):

Below are the repro details to get the latest modified file.

1. Create 2 variables, one to store the latest file name and the second variable to store the last modified date and assign an initial date value (least date) to it.

[image]

2. Using Get Metadata1, get the list of file names.
3. Pass the Output child items of `Get Metadata1` to ForEach activity.
4. Inside ForEach activity, add another `Get Metadata2` to get the last modified date of the current item (`@item().name`)

[image]

5. Connect Get Metadata2 to the `If Condition` activity. Add a condition to check if the Get Metdata2 output last modified date is greater than the initial date variable value.

   ```
   @greater(ticks(activity('Get Metadata2').output.lastModified),ticks(formatDateTime(variables('initial_date'))))
   ```

[image]

6. If the condition satisfies, then add set variable activity inside true to capture the current file name.

[image]

7. Ignore if the condition is false.
8. The file name which is stored after the ForEach loop is completed is the last modified file. Use this variable (file_name) in your later activities.